# Using DJL Inference for LSTM Model

Tags: java, djl

I am trying to perform inference on the LSTM model using **DJL** Framework. I would like to understand how to setup model inference **Translator**. The example in the tutorials section refers to mostly CNN and NLP model inference. My feature array looks like this,

```
[[feature_value1, feature_value2, feature_value3], [feature_value1, feature_value2, feature_value3]]
```

Is is possible to setup a Inference Translator based on this feature array and perform a model inference using **DJL** Framework?